# Specify which python version pylint should evaluate for

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

I'm using Sublime Text 3 With [Pylinter](https://github.com/biermeester/Pylinter) to run `pylint` on my files.

However, on the same machine, I work on files for both python 2, and python 3 projects (the code is executed on one of several remote test-VMs, via SSH. I'm modifying the files by opening them over SMB. This is my home test-lab, and I'm finally sitting down to learn py3k).

Can I easily override the mechanism pylint uses to determine the python version it should lint for? Ideally, there would be an inline directive, but I have not had much luck finding anything.

I'm (editing) on Windows (the remote VMs are linux, but that' irrelevant here), for what it's worth.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

AFAIK Pylint lints for the version of Python it is running on and it is not possible to override it.

Comment: @gurney-alex is right. This is because pylint rely both on the parser and the ast representation provided by the python distribution.

Comment: I see. I didn't realize how deeply it hooked into the python parser to work. I assumed it was interpreting the code internally, rather then operating on the AST generated by running the local python interpreter against it.

Comment: I'm not sure this is entirely correct. I am running Python 2.7.3, yet pylint reports `warning (W0622, redefined-builtin, ) Redefining built-in 'bytes'`. `bytes()` is not a built-in in python 2.

Answer (score 33):

You can try `python2 -m pylint ...` and `python3 -m pylint ...`. That ensures that you use the right version.

Comment: Perfect, I think this  is the best answer. Of course you have to install pylint on both of your python installation. (`pip2 install pylint` and `pip3 install pylint`)

Comment: This method will add the current directory to the path, so make sure it doesn't contain a file called `pylint.py` or conflict with any indirect imports like `astroid` (probably a safe assumption for your own code, but dangerous if trying to automatically analyse third party repos)

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on @sthenault's answer and borrowing heavily from @simon's to a [very similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340940/installing-pylint-for-python3-on-ubuntu) on **askubuntu**, the solution is to write a wrapper script around `pylint` that executes it with the appropriate version of the Python interpreter. Drop the following into a script called `mypylint` (or whatever) somewhere in your `$PATH`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

python_interpreter="python${1}"
pylint_args="-f colorized ${@:2}"
pylint_import=$(cat << PYTHON
import sys
import pkg_resources

__requires__ = "pylint"
sys.exit(
    pkg_resources.load_entry_point("pylint", "console_scripts", "pylint")()
)
PYTHON
)

$python_interpreter -c "$pylint_import" $pylint_args
```

Then, execute it like so: `mypylint 2|3 PYLINT_ARGS`. For instance:

```
mypylint 2 -f colorized module.py
```

I'm not sure how you can tie that into sublime-text, but it more generally answers the question of parallel versions of `pylint`. I also bundled the above solution into a [gist](https://gist.github.com/sevko/919e28588e455a6d5024).

Answer (score 2):

This is good, but I think the simplest thing is just to use virtualenv, and install pylint in each virtualenv. The correct pylint and python interpreter will be used.

Comment: Thanks. I had virtualenv and used pylint but it wasn't installed in my virtualenv so pylint used the global one instead which caused problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can override on a per-project level in Sublime Text by changing the pylint executable setting in Project->Edit Project to include:

```
"settings":
{
    "SublimeLinter.linters.pylint.executable": ["py", "-3.4", "-m", "pylint"],
}
```

substituting 3.4 for your preferred flavour

Comment: on my windows machine the command is instead `["C:\\python27\\python.exe", "-m", "pylint"]`, which uses the literal Python executable path -> can use the literal path for your particular python.exe of interest

Comment: ... for example, that of a virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

[As of 2021](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whatsnew/2/2.11/full.html?highlight=py-version#what-s-new-in-pylint-2-11-0), pylint supports `py-version`.

```
# Minimum Python version to use for version dependent checks. Will default to
# the version used to run pylint.
py-version=2.7
```

However, it doesn't seem to be perfect: eg, targeting 2.7 it doesn't warn about `yield from`, introduced in 3.3. It does warn about some things, such as f-strings.

Answer (score -1):

You should have two pylint installations, say pylint2 and pylint3, then write a wrapper script that will subprocess the desired one.

Answer (score -1):

You can install pylint3 which will evaluate for python 3.0, and pylint which will evaluate the code as python 2.7 by default.