# pylint syntax error on valid program (raise with three arguments / expressions)

Tags: python, exception, pylint, raise

I'm looking at this minimal valid(?) program:

```
import sys

def f():
    try:
        raise Exception()
    except Exception:
        raise Exception(), None, sys.exc_info()[2]

f()
```

This program executes and behaves as expected , preserving the stack trace of the inner exception, as documented by `help("raise")`. However, when I run `pylint` on it, this is what I get:

```
$ pylint program.py 
************* Module tmp
E:  7, 0: invalid syntax (<string>, line 7) (syntax-error)
```

The syntax-error disappears when I remove the second and third expressions to `raise`.

**Is this a bug in pylint, or am I overlooking something?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pylint binary testing for Python 3 syntax, your code is valid for Python 2 only. Pylint tests code following the syntax of the Python binary you installed it with (it uses Python's own parser).

In Python 3, you'd use:

```
raise Exception().with_traceback(sys.exc_info()[2])
```

See the [`raise` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) documentation for Python 3.

While your *syntax* may be correct for Python 2, you are technically using `raise` wrong. When passing in 3 elements, the first must be a *class*, not an instance. The second is an instance of that class, the third the traceback:

```
raise Exception, Exception(), sys.exc_info()[2]
```

or you can pass in `None` for an empty argument list passed to the first (the class) to create an instance:

```
raise Exception, None, sys.exc_info()[2]
```

Your code still happens to work, but only because Python isn't being too strict and takes that first argument as the instance when it is not a class.

If you want to test Python 2 code with pylint, install a copy into your Python 2 binary, and run that version. See [Specify which python version pylint should evaluate for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052637/specify-which-python-version-pylint-should-evaluate-for)

Comment: I completely forgot how I had installed pylint with python3, thank you!
Regarding using `raise` wrong, the documentation on my machine explicitly states that `If the first object is an instance, the type of the exception is the class of the instance, the instance itself is the value, and the second object must be "None".`. Did this happen to change across versions?