# How to set python-mode so linters check for python 3 versus python 2 errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint, python-mode, pylama

To All,

How do I set python-mode so the linters check for Python 3 versus Python 2 errors depending on if I am editing a Python 3 or a Python 2 file?  After the last update of python-mode, the linters seems to be defaulting to Python 3.  For example there are lots of complaints about print statements - print "hello world" instead of print functions - print("hello world") when I am in a Python 2 file.

Note that let g:pymode_python = 'python' is not the solution so I could not find an answer in :help pymode

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Kind of late for this question but here is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45334238/5861873).

Comment: Yup, I know the old "python -m pylint trick", but that is really not a solution to the problem that I posted as it is calling pylint from outside of Vim and not from within Vim using python-mode as I posted