# way to infer python version requirement?

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

When publishing a package, I need to tell users which version of python they require. I've been developing against Python 3.6, but I don't know how far backwards compatible my code is (or my dependencies).

Is there a static analysis tool / version guide to help me figure this out?

I'm sure this is impossible to do with regard to 3rd party dependencies, but is there a static analysis tool that might help? This seems like the sort of thing `pylint` could help with, but it doesn't appear to.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45334238/319034) answer seems to imply I might set up, for example, a `conda` environment for each sub version of python 3, install and run `pylint` from each. Maybe that's the best I can do?

Comment: I don't know of any automated tools, but it seems like a common enough problem that one should exist. Instead of using pylint going backwards from 3.6, I would start at 3.0 and move forwards until your project works. Then that's the minimum version.

Comment: First cut: don't bother supporting any version that is already end-of-life (<3.5):
https://devguide.python.org/#status-of-python-branches